# Как исправить этот sql запрос, чтобы он работал корректно?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Имеется MySQL таблица Sakila Sample Database.Пытаюсь выполнить задание:

Нужно одним запросом вывести `id` клиента, полное имя (ФИ), адрес, округ, город, страна, сумма платежей клиента в 2006 году, количество арендованных клиентом фильмов за все время. И это все только по жителям РФ.

Я в своих рассуждениях пришел к двум запросам. Оба работают не совсем корректно.

1.

```
select distinct a.ID, a.name, a.address, a.city, c.district, a.country
     , if(year(b.payment_date)=2006, sum(b.amount), 0) as SUM_payments
     , count(d.customer_id) as Total_Films 
from customer_list a 
left join payment b on a.ID=b.customer_id 
join address c on a.address=c.address 
left join rental d on b.rental_id=d.rental_id 
where a.country = 'Russian Federation' 
group by a.ID, b.amount, b.payment_date, c.district order by a.name;
```

2. 

```
select distinct a.ID, a.name, a.address, a.city, b.district, a.country
     , if(year(c.payment_date)=2006, sum(c.amount), 0) as SUM_payments
     , count(d.customer_id) as Quantity_Films 
from customer_list a 
join address b on a.address=b.address 
join payment c on a.ID=c.customer_id 
join rental d on a.ID=d.customer_id 
where a.country = 'Russian Federation' 
group by c.customer_id, c.payment_date, b.district order by a.name;
```

Проблема с последними двумя столбцами: перестраивая запрос, я добиваюсь корректного подсчета либо одного, либо второго. Никак не могу разобраться, чем это можно пофиксить. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Также сам запрос возможно построен полностью некорректно, т.к. у меня не получилось полностью убрать лишние строки в выводе с помощью `distinct`. Но и эту проблему я не понимаю как решить.

[первый случай](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL39w.png)

[второй случай](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuiJp.png)

Comment: Почему-то не отобразился второй скрин:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuiJp.png

Comment: особо не вчитывался, но там вам `left join` наверное нужен. зы distinct не требуется при наличии правильного group by

Comment: при этом условие на 2006 переносится в джойн

Comment: алиасы таблицам давайте не по алфавиту, а по сокращениям `customers - c, payments as p`, куда понятнее будет код писать, и уж тем более читать

Comment: Вы пытаетесь получить агрегированные данные по двум разным таблицам. Безнадёжное занятие (JOIN multiplying). Агрегируйте отдельные таблицы в подзапросах. Хотя в данном частном случае (по дальней таблице нужно количество) можно попробовать обойтись COUNT(DISTINCT).

Comment: благодарю за советы!)